# RegEx to check first character as + and others are only numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

My use case is to validate a String only consists of + and the numbers. I have tried with so many regexes but couldn't able to fix my issue.

I have used `/^[0-9]+$/` regex but it is failed in the 2 nd and 3rd(Obviously it is because it is having A Character) input.

My need is,

```
if the input is 00000094777216903 - TRUE
if the input is +947777216903     - TRUE (+ is fine if it is in the beginning of the string)
if the input is +947777216903A    - FALSE
if the input is 0000777216903A    - FALSE
```

Can anyone help me to achieve my need in JS.

Comment: And the problem is? Add an optional `+` before the number part

Comment: Have you tried this one? `^\+[0-9]+$`

Comment: I am getting [Invalid regular expression: //^+[0-9]+$//: Nothing to repeat] error.

Comment: Of course you do, because `+` is a _quantifier_, and a quantifier with nothing _to_ quantify before it, makes no sense. That’s why you need to _escape_ the +, so that it is not taken as a quantifier any more, just as @melancia has shown - `\+`

Comment: Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/qfJmkK/1

Comment: Yes, I am really new, may be 0.

Comment: If the `+` sign is optional, @Leonardum answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex
https://regex101.com/r/6wW84L/2

```
/(\+){0,1}[0-9]+$/
```

You have a working example below
This /(+){0,1}[0-9]+$/
not //(+){0,1}[0-9]+$//

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do the trick:

```
/\+?[0-9]+/
```

Let me know if this does not, maybe I can adjust my answer.

Also, maybe this site will help you to find the exact RegEx you are looking for: https://www.regextester.com. I sure find it to be a handy tool!

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\+?\d+$/
```

Explanation:

`\+?` Optional "+" character.

`\d+` Multiple numerical characters.

`^` and `$` matches entire strings (as opposed to searching within other strings)